# How I can use ArrayList field in Jooq with update statement

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jooq

I have a problem with jooq version 3.14.6. I wanna to use an update statement for fields search - pr_id and m_id like this:

```
public Result<?> save(Long id, Request req) {
   Condition condition = field("send.pr_id").eq(id)
                .and(field("send.m_id").eq(req.getMemId));

   condition = req.applyConditions(condition);

   return ctx.update(table(snp).as("send"))
              .set(field("status"), "D")
              .where(condition)
              .returning()
              .fetch();
}
```

Also in class Request i have this code:

```
public class Request {
   Integer prId;

   List<Long> memId;

   public Condition applyConditions(Condition condition) {
       Condition mod = condition;

       if(Objects.nonNull(prId)) {
          mod = mod.and(field("send.pr_id")).eq(prId);
       }

       if(Objects.nonNull(memId)) {
          mod = mod.and(field("send.m_id")).eq(memId);
       }
       return modified;
   }
}
```

in my table i have columns - `pr_id bigint not null, status char(1) not null, m_id bigint not null etc..`

When i start my project and use rest request(http://localhost:8080/api/v1/pr/17) in postman like so:

> {    "memId": [
> 2, 4, 6
> ] }

i get error:

> "Type class java.util.ArrayList is not supported in dialect postgres"

This error tied with uncorrect field memId

How can i correct this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot compare a column with a list in SQL, using `=`. Just use the [`IN` predicate](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/conditional-expressions/in-predicate/) instead:

```java
field("send.m_id").in(memId)
```

Please note: [I strongly recommend you use jOOQ with code generation](https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-use-jooq-with-code-generation/), unless your schema is dynamic. But given you're passing constant string literals for your table/column names, it probably isn't.